# getRandomInt() error undefined for class

Tags: java

in this code

```
class randomArray
{
  int[] array1;
  randomArray()
{

Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
 do{
  System.out.println("Please enter an interger value between 5-10");
  array1 = new int[userInput.nextInt()];
 }while(array1.length>10||array1.length<5);
}
public void assignment()
{
  for(int counter=array1.length-1;counter >=0;counter--)
 {
  array1[counter] = getRandomInt(1, 50);//(Math.random()*(50-1))+1;
 }
}
public void display()
 {
  System.out.println("Array="+array1); 
 }
}
```

i get the error 
 The method getRandomInt(int, int) is undefined for the type randomArray
randomArray is my class name

can anyone inform me on what this error means

i am using dr java with the eclipse compiler

Comment: Where you delcared `array1` ?

Comment: show your full class, as the error says the method does not exist in your class. Most likely a typo error

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ  more code added

Comment: @Juned Ahsan more code added

Comment: Is this your homework? :)

Answer (score 1):

> i get the error The method getRandomInt(int, int) is undefined for the type randomArray randomArray is my class name
>
> can anyone inform me on what this error means

It means what is says, you haven't added a *method* with the signature `getRandomInt(int, int)` to `randomArray`. Something like<sup>**1**</sup>,

```
public static int getRandomInt(int a, int b) {
    return (int) ((Math.random() * (b - a)) + a);
}
```

<sup>**1**<sub>Based on the code in your comment.</sub></sup>

Comment: when i tried using the (Math.random()*(50-1))+1; i have in a comment it say my array is int which i made it but then the Math.random returns a double so the two wont fit is there any way i could use Math.random but put it into the int??@Elliott Frisch

Comment: **Yes**. See my *answer*; `array1[counter] = (int) ((Math.random() * (50 - 1)) + 1);`